# JBOSS Standalone HornetQ Multicast cluster throws loop in the cluster

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq

I have provided my messaging configuration below. Can anyone please let me know why hornetq loop in cluster occurs. In all the instances, we deleted the data and temp directory before starting the server. All the servers are started with localhost as bind address.

Can anyone specify do we need to keep the `<local-bind-port>` as same for all the nodes in the cluster.

We have configured Multicast Cluster (HornetQ) with JBOSS 7.1.1 Final. When we start 3 instances of JBOSS servers in 3 separate physical servers, it starts to load my log with this message

> 18:38:14,325 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl] (Thread-13 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa-23095497)) Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@1a3fe65 [name=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa]]@192b987 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@1a3fe65 [name=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa]]@192b987 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@30045119[nodeUUID=458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa, connector=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost, address=jms, server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa])) [initialConnectors=[org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
>
> 18:38:14,388 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionImpl] (Thread-4 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-20937207)) MessageFlowRecordImpl [nodeID=3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, connector=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost, queueName=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa]]@192b987, isClosed=false, firstReset=true]::Remote queue binding jms.queue.extractorQueue458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa has already been bound in the post office. Most likely cause for this is you have a loop in your cluster due to cluster max-hops being too large or you have multiple cluster connections to the same nodes using overlapping addresses
>
> 18:38:14,391 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionImpl] (Thread-4 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-20937207)) MessageFlowRecordImpl [nodeID=3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, connector=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost, queueName=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa]]@192b987, isClosed=false, firstReset=true]::Remote queue binding jms.queue.outputQueue458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa has already been bound in the post office. Most likely cause for this is you have a loop in your cluster due to cluster max-hops being too large or you have multiple cluster connections to the same nodes using overlapping addresses
>
> 18:38:14,395 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionImpl] (Thread-4 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-20937207)) MessageFlowRecordImpl [nodeID=3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, connector=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost, queueName=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.3afb4e60-ed20-11e1-831c-109add44c09e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa]]@192b987, isClosed=false, firstReset=true]::Remote queue binding jms.queue.expiryQueue458fb681-ed23-11e1-8bbf-c42c031d96aa has already been bound in the post office. Most likely cause for this is you have a loop in your cluster due to cluster max-hops being too large or you have multiple cluster connections to the same nodes using overlapping addresses
>
> 12:11:35,018 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl] (Thread-20 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa-11515472)) Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@17f9401 [name=sf.config-cluster.ffb4ee03-ecec-11e1-86b2-109add44c09e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.ffb4ee03-ecec-11e1-86b2-109add44c09e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa]]@cdd17f targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@17f9401 [name=sf.config-cluster.ffb4ee03-ecec-11e1-86b2-109add44c09e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.ffb4ee03-ecec-11e1-86b2-109add44c09e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa]]@cdd17f targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@20566889[nodeUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa, connector=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost, address=jms, server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa])) [initialConnectors=[org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
>
> 12:11:32,673 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-server-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa-11515472)) Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@147e4f0 [name=sf.config-cluster.2ab34008-eced-11e1-ad90-109add5d2b6e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.2ab34008-eced-11e1-ad90-109add5d2b6e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa]]@1074938 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@147e4f0 [name=sf.config-cluster.2ab34008-eced-11e1-ad90-109add5d2b6e, queue=QueueImpl[name=sf.config-cluster.2ab34008-eced-11e1-ad90-109add5d2b6e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa]]@1074938 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@20566889[nodeUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa, connector=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost, address=jms, server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=9287734d-eced-11e1-b554-c42c031d96aa])) [initialConnectors=[org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=localhost], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected

The configuration is:

```
        <hornetq-server>
            <clustered>true</clustered>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <cluster-user>myconfig</cluster-user>
            <cluster-password>mycluster</cluster-password>
            <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="5"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="5"/>
            </acceptors>

            <broadcast-groups>
                <broadcast-group name="bg-config">
                    <local-bind-port>9877</local-bind-port>
                    <group-address>224.1.22.1</group-address>
                    <group-port>9876</group-port>
                    <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
                    <connector-ref>
                        netty
                    </connector-ref>
                </broadcast-group>
            </broadcast-groups>

            <discovery-groups>
                <discovery-group name="dg-config">
                    <group-address>224.1.22.1</group-address>
                    <group-port>9876</group-port>
                    <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
                </discovery-group>
            </discovery-groups>

            <cluster-connections>
                <cluster-connection name="config-cluster">
                    <address>jms</address>
                    <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                    <forward-when-no-consumers>true</forward-when-no-consumers>
                    <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                    <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-config"/>
                </cluster-connection>
            </cluster-connections>

            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>

            <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>500</redelivery-delay>
                    <max-delivery-attempts>5000</max-delivery-attempts>
                    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                    <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                    <connection-ttl>-1</connection-ttl>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                    <connection-ttl>-1</connection-ttl>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="testQueue">
                    <entry name="queue/test"/>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="expiryQueue">
                    <entry name="queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-topic name="testTopic">
                    <entry name="topic/test"/>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/test"/>
                </jms-topic>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 3):

The erros refers to the configuration of multicast in your network.

You can stop error messages adding the configuration above on hornetq settings:

```
<cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
    <reconnect-attempts>2</reconnect-attempts>
    ...
</cluster-connection>

-1 = infinity (default)
2 = 2 times
```

But I didn't use this. I changed my multicast address to 224.0.0.1 instead of the default 231.7.7.7, in  like this:

```
<socket-binding-group name="full-ha-sockets" default-interface="public">
    ...
    <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:224.0.0.1}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: So this question has 2 years but I hope you will still look at it. @Elvis this works really well but can you explain me why ?